# SQL Value Change Tracking with Date on which value got changed

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way to track the change in value of any columns when someone makes an update in SQL database.

Comment: People often put extra columns in tables for this... Like `lastUpdate` and `lastUser` which are then updated by a trigger on every insert/update.

Comment: [temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) may be what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: **Change Data Capture(CDC)** it requires coding effort from your side in order to handle these changes or added data, in addition to the performance impact of the triggers on the system.When Change Data Capture is enabled on a user table, a new system table will be created with the same structure of that source table, with extra columns to include the changes metadata

---

Option 2: **Change Tracking(CT)** introduced in SQL Server 2008 Enterprise. CT works in all SQL Server editions such as Express, Workgroup, Web, Standard, Enterprise and DataCenter.